# Перевод html-страницы в word- документ

Tags: php, javascript

Есть html-страница.

```
<div id="description"  >
```

[image]

```
<h2>Умей действовать при пожаре</h2>

        <div style="text-align: center"><Img src="/images/goods/1552_zagl.jpg"
                                             border="0" alt="Оформление кабинета ОБЖ" title="Оформление кабинета ОБЖ" style="margin: 0 3px;"></div>         
        <h3>Краткое описание:</h3>
        <div id="description_tab"></div>

                        <table>
                                    <Tr>
                                        <Td colsapn=2 vAlign="top" class="chnamecell">
                                            <Span class="smalltext"><B>Параметры:</B></Span><Br />
                                        </Td>
                                    </Tr></table><table>
                                    <Tr>
                                        <Td width="30%" vAlign="top" class="chnamecell">
                                            <Span class="smalltext"><B>Размер</B></Span><Br />
                                        </Td>
                                        <Td width="70%" vAlign="top" class="chvaluecell">
                                            <Span class="smalltext">2,8 х 1,0 м</Span><Br />
                                        </Td>
                                    </Tr></table><table>
                                    <Tr>
                                        <Td width="30%" vAlign="top" class="chnamecell">
                                            <Span class="smalltext"><B>Вес</B></Span><Br />
                                        </Td>
                                        <Td width="70%" vAlign="top" class="chvaluecell">
                                            <Span class="smalltext">8,3 кг</Span><Br />
                                        </Td>
                                    </Tr></table>           <p>Бренд: NATIONAL® </p>
        <p>Цена производителя: 9800 руб.</p>
        <p>Код производителя: 10633</p>
        <p>Стенд сборный. Комплектующие изготовлены из противоударного полистирола УПС-825,методом литья под давлением в пресс-формах с окрашиванием в массе исходного полимера.<br>
            Размеры элементов:<br>
            Ячейка А4 формата - 250 х375 х 25 мм<br>
            Ячейка А3 формата - 375 х500 х 25 мм<br>
            Фриз 125 х125 х 20 мм<br>
            Сектор 125х125 х 20 мм<br>
            Овал 125хх125 х20 мм<br>
            Плакаты А4,  А3 форма<br>
            Сертификат (соответствие) не требуется.<br>
            Клас безопасности по ОПБ 88/97 - 4н.<br>
            Дополнительно: модификации базовой сборки могут отличаться (цвет, заголовок стенда, логотипы) – информируется доп. соглашением. </p>
```

В ней присутствует такой див - из него нужно создать документ .doc .docx.
Пробовал html-docx-js, однако полученные файлы читаются только в ворде.
Пробовал использовать такую функцию:

```
function get_doc() {
var a = document.createElement('a');
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
var table_div = document.getElementById('desc_main_1');
var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
a.download = 'planerka_table_' + '.doc';
a.click();
}
```

Тут наоборот в либра офисе отрабатывает (с багами), но часть браузеров тупо разметку сохраняет. 
Есть ли какие то способы на javascript или php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гораздо проще сохранять в pdf, для этого существует очень много библиотек, в частности DOMPDF, позволяющая экспортировать html в pdf. С dok все гораздо сложнее, но если html постоянно одинаков, то можно воспользоватся библотекой ["PHPWord"](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), и генерировать .doc "на лету", подставляя значения.

Comment: А вы пользовались данной библиотекой. Поставил ее, сделал данный basicExample https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html, однако выходит просто пустой файл.

Comment: разобрался, оказывается он сохраняет документ на сервере, а можно ли сохранять документ на клиентской машине?

Comment: можно использовать костыль, сохранить на машине клиентской, а на сервере удалить